# Unable to delete row from table

Tags: sql, database, delete-row

I have two database `main` and `main_2` and two tables `table1` in the `main` database and `table2` in the `main_2` database.

I want to delete rows from `table2` which are not in `table1` and I am using following query:

```
delete from main_2.dcl.table2
where slno not in (select slno from main.dcl.table1)
```

I am getting

> 0 row(s) affected

But actually the rows are present in `table2`, I checked manually.

Comment: What datatype is `slno`? Please post some sample data.

Comment: and does this return what you expect? `select dcl.table2.slno, table1.slno from main_2.dcl.table2
left outer join main.dcl.table1 on dcl.table1.slno = dcl.table2.slno`